# Awaited async Task loses HttpContext.Current

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, rhino-mocks

I have a very bizarre situation regarding a Web Application that makes an asynchronous Http Post...

We have two branches in TFS.  I merged code from one branch to another and then find that some Integration Tests in the new branch fail due to a System.NullReferenceException.  I spend time ensuring that our code in both branches is identical, and all the referenced DLLs are identical too.  Everything seems identical.

So, I decide to debug the test.

What our test does is to create a Mock IHttpClient object.  We stub the Mock object in such a way that the clientMock.PostAsyncWithResponseMessage(x,y) returns a new HttpResponseMessage() object (on which we've set various properties).

So, the code looks like this:

```
using (var response = await client.PostAsyncWithResponseMessage(url, postData).ConfigureAwait(true))
{
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        ret.Response = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
        ret.ContentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString();
    }

    ret.StatusCode = response.StatusCode.ToInt();
}
```

Taking this a line at a time:

```
await client.PostAsyncWithResponseMessage(url, postData).ConfigureAwait(true))
```

This looks like it's an async method, but "client" is our Mock object so all it is doing is supporting the IHttpClient interface.  If you inspect the Thread, the ID does not change when executing this line.

Later on, we have:

```
await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
```

Now, when this line executes, the HttpContext.Current is set to null - all our context is trashed.  In this application, we do not call ConfigureAwait(false) anywhere, so as far as I'm aware there's no reason why we should lose the context.

If I change that line to:

```
response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Then this is of course blocking and we don't lose the context.

So two questions:

1. Why would the await method().ConfigureAwait(true) lose the context?  [More marks will of course be awarded if one can also suggest why identical code from one TFS branch fails whilst working in a different branch, but I'm not expecting that]
2. I can see the obvious benefits of awaiting the .PostAsyncWithResponseMessage(url, postData) method since our thread would otherwise be blocked as the other server processed our request.  However, having retrieved the data, what advantage is there in awaiting the ReadAsStringAsync()....in other words, is there a good reason **not** to use the .Result syntax?

thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: @Nkosi: I'm fairly familiar with this great article and believe that we follow all the declared best practices.  Would you please point me to the specific part of this article that you are suggesting I read.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> If you inspect the Thread, the ID does not change when executing this line.

This does not necessarily mean that it ran synchronously. Most unit test frameworks provide a free-threaded context (`SynchronizationContext.Current` is `null`) and run their tests on a thread pool thread. It is entirely possible for the code to just happen to resume on the same thread (especially if you were only running one test).

> Now, when this line executes, the `HttpContext.Current` is set to `null` - all our context is trashed. In this application, we do not call `ConfigureAwait(false)` anywhere, so as far as I'm aware there's no reason why we should lose the context.

I assume `SynchronizationContext.Current` is set to `null`, so there *isn't* actually a context. What's probably happening is that the test is setting `HttpContext.Current` (on some random thread pool thread), and after the first truly asynchronous operation, sometimes the test resumes on a thread where `Current` is set and sometimes it doesn't.

On ASP.NET, [there's a request context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) (`SynchronizationContext`) that handles the propagation of `HttpContext.Current`. If you don't have something similar in your unit tests, then there's no context to preserve `HttpContext.Current`.

If you are looking for a quick fix, then you can probably use my [`AsyncContext` type](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/tree/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Context). This will provide a single-threaded context so that all your asynchronous code will resume on the same thread - not the same semantics as ASP.NET's context, but similar enough to be useful for some tests:

```
void TestMethod()
{
  AsyncContext.Run(async () =>
  {
    // Test method body goes here.
  });
}
```

On a side note, `ConfigureAwait(true)` is just noise; `true` is the default behavior.

> is there a good reason not to use the `.Result` syntax?

It's not clear from your code that the server's response is actually read by the time `PostAsyncWithResponseMessage` completes. Based on the descriptions of your problem (and the fact that `Result` fixes it in your tests), it sounds like `ReadAsStringAsync` is in fact acting asynchronously.

If this is the case, then there are two good reasons not to block: 1) You're blocking a thread unnecessarily, and 2) You're opening yourself up to [deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: Your post really helped and I found the issue. Turned out that in both TFS branches, HttpContext.Current was set to null.  However, we use an IOC context (buried deep in a common assembly) and found that our singleton had been marked as [ThreadStatic] in a different application that shares the common assembly.  This IOC was set to null in one branch, but not the other and is the cause of our issue.  Regarding the side note - adding ConfigureAwait(true) will tell us in n-years time that it was a deliberate decision taken by the developer (and shouldn't be set to false).  Thanks!